# How can i overwrite this style of jquery ui

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui

I'm trying to overwrite the style of some element of jquery ui, this is my html

```
    <div class="menu ui-accordion-header ui-state-default ui-corner-all">
        <label class="formatText" id="lblIndicators">
            Cliente</label>
        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-e menuIcon" style="float: right"></span>
        <div class="subMenu ui-accordion-header ui-helper-reset ui-state-default ui-corner-all">
            <ul class="options">
                <li>
                    <label class="formatText">
                        Ver Cliente</label>
                    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s" style="float: right"></span>
                    <div class="subMenuRight ui-accordion-header ui-helper-reset ui-state-default ui-corner-all">
                        <ul class="options">
                            <li>Por Nombre</li>
                            <li>Por Año de ingreso</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>algo</li>
                <li>cualquier vaina</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**note** that the div has the follow classes `menu ui-accordion-header ui-state-default ui-corner-all` now i'm trying to overwrite the classes like this

```
.menu .ui-state-default
{
    width:120px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background: #003E6F;
    float:left;
}

.menu .ui-helper-reset
{
    width:120px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background: #003E6F;
    float:left;
}

.menu .ui-accordion-header
{
    width:120px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background: #003E6F;
    float:left;
}

.menu .ui-state-hover{
     border-width: 0;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #003E6F;

}

.subMenu
{
    display:none;
    width:129px;
}

.subMenuRight
{
    display:none;
    width:120px;
    position:absolute;
    left:100%;
    top:0px;
}
```

Now my problem it's that first element div, doesn't get the override of the class. All the children divs works well. What i'm doing wrong??

[This is my live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZxvkN/20/)

Comment: Why not edit the original CSS files the come with jQuery UI, or maybe make your own theme?

Comment: thanks for asking, but it's not an option, because i'm using some elements with style of the jquery-ui and others, based in some parts of the jquery-ui

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first CSS declaration, try using this instead:

```
.menu.ui-state-default, .menu .ui-state-default
{
    width:120px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background: #003E6F;
    float:left;
}
```

In your code, `.menu .ui-state-default` doesn't apply to the outermost div (`<div class="menu ui-accordion-header ui-state-default ui-corner-all">`) because that code is targeting elements with the class of `ui-state-default` within elements with a class of `menu`.

The first div has both classes so you would also need to use this `.menu.ui-state-default` to apply the styles to that div.

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript doesn't do anything to change the div class. The main div has class menu, and the functions you bind to its events find the spans inside it and change their class.

Answer (score 0):

In theory you should just be able to put it into a stylesheet and have it work as long as you're linking your custom styles after wherever the jQuery UI styles are.